# How to get a rematch with resigned user?

Tags: draw-something

I started a game with an random opponent. But after 68 moves she suddenly resigned. I think it was an accident. Problem is: I don't have this user as a friend on Facebook nor do I know her email. How can restart a game with her? All I know are her first name and initial of last name

Comment: I see no reason to believe you can...

Comment: post to Craigslist missed connections.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot find her until destiny matches you, again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to create game then select username and type in their user name it should be able to lead you back to the same person

Comment: I don't know her username, just her display name and it says Helen A. I tried starting a game with Helen A and it stated a game with a different user!!